# Vim PHP ctags for $['array'] C+]

Tags: php, vim, ctags

So far I have this (Which is sufficient enough for me at the moment):

```
ctags -R --languages=php --langmap=PHP:+.tpl --tag-relative=yes --PHP-kinds=+cf
```

However, I still can't press `"C-]"` when I want to goto the definition of an array or variable in another file.

My guess is that this is because of PHP preceeding variables with $ or because I need some flag in `--PHP-kinds` ?

Comment: For PHP, `ctags` supports `c`lasses, `i`nterfaces, constant `d`efinitions, `f`unctions, `v`ariables and… `j`avascript functions by default. It has no `a`rray "kind", if that's what you are after. What about dropping `--tag-relative=yes`?

Comment: actually I miss the variables too in the tags file, is it only required to add "v" to `--php-kinds` ? I did that but it doesn't appear variables are there ..

Comment: You don't need `--php-kinds` at all.